# What grammar and vocabulary should you know before a CEFR B1.1 course?

Tags: education

I have the opportunity to undertake both B1.1 and B1.2 German courses through my employer. In an ideal situation, what **exactly** should I already know in terms of grammar and vocabulary before undertaking a B1.1 course? I find the CEFR language level descriptors very vague for ascertaining what precisely I should have already learned in A1.1 and A2.2 courses.

Some background: I am almost entirely self-taught in German. I first used the *Michel Thomas Total German* and *Perfect German* audio courses for my foundation in the language. Since then I have enjoyed opportunities for extended stays in Austria and Germany, where I have sought to improve my mastery of the language by speaking to locals exclusively in German. To date, this has worked incredibly well. The working language of my current occupation is entirely German. However I feel as if there are considerable gaps in my knowledge, seeing as as I have learned predominantly via *"learning by doing"*.

Comment: You might try taking a practice test on-line. There are many available and I'm sure you can turn up several with a Google search. In my limited experience with them, the tests don't just cover vocabulary and grammar, things you can learn from a book, but also what you can only learn with practice. For example understanding a PA announcement in a noisy train station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer concerning vocabulary:

There exist word lists, like this [Goethe-Institut: A2](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/de/Goethe-Zertifikat_A2_Wortliste.pdf).
Note, that the online dictionary [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Liste), here the entry for *Liste*, also states the associated level.

Answer (score 0):

The Goethe Institute also has an [online self-assessment test](https://www.goethe.de/en/spr/kup/tsd.html) which will give you a good idea of what grammar is required and what level you currently are.

I've also just found a whole page of [vocabulary lists](https://www.heylama.com/blog/free-german-vocabulary-lists), including the Goethe ones up to B1 and an organisation I'm not familiar with called Aspekte Neu which has lists from B1 to C1

Comment: I just tried the online self-assessment test from Göthe, and figured I would leave a comment for anybody curious.

The test contained 30 questions, and at the end didn't identify a formal level from the CEFR. Instead it just said "Great! You can handle almost all situations with your level of German".